# The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I typed `apt-get install phpmyadmin` and ran into an error saying it cannot connect to mysql (socket issue). It was normal because I forget to install mysql *before*, so I selected "abort" above all options given by phpmyadmin.

Then `sudo tasksel` and installed `lamp server`.

Once finished, I ran :

```
apt-get remove --purge phpmyadmin
apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Then `mysql -u root -p` but I got the following error: `Access denied for the following user 'root'@'localhost'`

So I solved this problem by doing :

```
mysql
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('mypassword'); 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Then I successfully logged in **localhost/phpmyadmin**, but found this message :

The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here.

I clicked *here*, and it showed me :
[image]

Can I go on peacefully with mysql/phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Make sure that all the $cfg['Servers'][$i] directives are uncommented!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[OP's answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/261858/revisions):

I solved this problem with the following :

```
cd /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples
sudo gunzip create_tables.sql.gz 
mysql -u root -p < create_tables.sql
mysql -u root -p -e 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ON phpmyadmin.* TO 'pma'@'localhost''
```

Then edited `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` on these lines :

```
/* Optional: User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapassword';
```

Logged back in phpmyadmin, and then, the warning message had disappeared.

Also note that you may have a new warning about phpmyadmin storage not completely configured. This can be caused because you need to tell phpmyadmin the name of the tables to use their features. That can be done editing `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` on this lines:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
```

Note the double underscore `__`.

Comment: I still had a minor issue I had to comment out the following:

Comment: //    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = $dbuser;
//    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = $dbuserpwd; to be pma and the password that was set.

Comment: Don't forget to log out and log back in.

Comment: @nwolybug mysql user permissions are [applied immediately](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privilege-changes.html)

Comment: and don't forget, to reflect the changes you need to login again in phpmyadmin. Page refresh will not work.

Answer (score 2):

I also had to change all the tables name in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` with double underscores ex.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
```

because that was the table created after `create_tables.sql` execution.

Answer (score 2):

VestaCP Team made and successfully tested a script to get rid of that annoying message "The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated". We hope the fix will be useful and help users. Visit the [Github page](https://github.com/skurudo/phpmyadmin-fixer) for code.

The script:

- Works from user root
- Makes a backup of `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` in `/root`
- Changes values in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`
- Adds a mysql user `pma` and the table `phpmyadmin` (if the user or the table already exist, the script will delete them!)
- Downloads and adds table for the database `phpmyadmin`
- Cleans temp files including leftover `pma.txt` (contains password for pma@localhost) and old config

Answer (score 2):

This Helped Me:

1. `sudo vim /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`
2. Add the following lines with the other $cfg['Servers'][$i]:

   `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite']         = 'pma__favorite';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent']           = 'pma__recent';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches']    = 'pma__savedsearches';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs']    = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking']         = 'pma__tracking';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig']       = 'pma__userconfig';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups']       = 'pma__usergroups';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking']         = 'pma__users';`
3. Now try to login to localhost/phpmyadmin. The error message should not show up any more.

In Short, whatever is the missing component error showing up just Add:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i][COMPONENT] = 'pma__COMPONENT';`

in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

Answer (score 1):

For me:
    I have to edited /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php on this line:

```
$dbname='phpmyadmin';
```

Comment: this helped me. without it, it worked only for root db user, with this also for the another one.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions provided here worked for me.

This issue is happening with the mysql update to 5.6 or 5.7 versions.

I solved it by installing phpmyadmin 4.7 version.

Enjoy